# splashscreen imageview not displaying images

Tags: android, android-imageview, splash-screen

Hi guys i have this splash screen with the layout main.xml which contains an imageview,
here is the main.xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/slide11" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my splashscreen.class  file

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
 try {  
           new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() 
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),content_activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            Main.this.finish();   }  }, 5000);
            } catch(Exception e){}
}
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {

        super.onBackPressed();
} }
```

when i try to run this in my emulator all works fine, but when i try to run it in a device through debugging mode i don't get the image specified in the imageView, but i get a white screen for the specified amount of time.any help would be much appreciated.

//edit : i double checked the res/drawable folder and i tried primarily using png and also gave a go using .gif none worked in the device. (device micromax a110)

Comment: check console once whether it throwing any exception?

Comment: i get this W/OpenGLRenderer(13960): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture, is there any limitations to the size of the image that has to be used ? the .png one is 1.04mb and the jpeg one is 867kb

Comment: looks like it was because of the size of the image, when reduced worked !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

looks like it was because of the size of the image, when reduced worked !!

Answer (score 7):

use this instead of your layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/slide11" >
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Use image as layout background :-

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
 android:background="@drawable/slide11"

 >

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: tried it but still i keep getting the white screen on the device

Comment: To avoid white screen use  `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"` in manifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

This can be happening due to issue in the manifest file. Here is an example of my manifest file which has 3 activities and 1 splash screen. Hoping that this helps out.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.foodorder">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.FoodOrder">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Final_activity" />
        <activity android:name=".Second_activity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: does the issue you posted as answer here, relates to how incorrect order? looks like there's no drawable setup in your snippet code cmiiw

Comment: the incorrect order is with respect to the manifest file and hence I've posted the manifest file snippet